# the same event delete a post simultaneously in two pages with angular2

Tags: firebase, angular

i'm learning angular2 and wonder how to delete the same post in two different pages at the same time.

i have two view 
1- home who display some posts 
2- client profile page , the client see all his posts and have the ability to delete them

```
remove(item){
  this.TaskService.deletepost("-KE7kC0dEcG1ph94TrAC", this.currentUserID).then(() => {
    let index = this.postByme.indexOf(item)
    this.postByme.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("deleteeeed")
  })
}
```

i'm using this  to delete post in the user profile page , using firebase as backend , the post is deleted as expected in the user profile page , but in the home page i have to reload the pages to see the same post deleted.

how can i build something who warn the home that this post has been deleted , and delete it too

Answer (score 1):

You could add an observable or a subject into the service that contains the delete method.

```
deletionNotification: Subject = new Subject();

remove(item){
  this.TaskService.deletepost("-KE7kC0dEcG1ph94TrAC", this.currentUserID).then(() => {
    let index = this.postByme.indexOf(item)
    this.postByme.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("deleteeeed")
    deletionNotification.emit({
      id: 'KE7kC0dEcG1ph94TrAC',
      userId: this.currentUserID
    }); 
  })
}
```

Parts that would like to be notified could simply subscribe on it.

```
this.service.deletionNotification.subscribe(
  (deletedItem) => {
    // Do something
  }
);
```